# Python - How to use a dictionary to map individual characters of a string

Tags: python

I am looking to use a dictionary to reference all 100 python characters to integers. Then apply the dictionary to a string.  I have been testing this on a small example but can't seem to get it right.

```
#Dict
printable = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4} 
#Sample string
test_string = 'abbcd'
#Apply the dict on the string
print([printable.index(x)+1 for x in test_string if x in printable])
```

The print statement fails with:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'index'
```

My desired output would be:

```
[1,2,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to output the values stored in the dictionary?

Comment: First of all, `prinatble` is a `dict`. You can't `index` it. You just need  `>>> [printable.get(x) for x in test_string]` `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: I would like the output stored in a list like this:  [1,2,2,3,4] @Ernxst

Comment: `[printable[x] for x in test_string] `
> `[1, 2, 2, 3, 4] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the printable (ASCII) characters are available as a string in Python in the `string` module: `string.printable`. In Python strings support the `.index()` method.

This means you can avoid the dictionary and use the string directly:

```
[string.printable.index(x) for x in test_string if x in string.printable]
```

Though if your string is long it will probably be a lot faster to build a dictionary first:

```
printable = dict((char, i+1) for i, char in enumerate(string.printable))
```

Answer (score 2):

`printable` is a dictionary and you can index it directly using the Python index operator `[]`:

```
print([printable[x] for x in test_string if x in printable])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map the dictionary method to get an item (`dict.get`) over the test string:

```
# just fetch the dictionary value for every character in the input
replacements = map(printable.get, test_string)

# make them strings since they're integers and you want to join them
string_replacements = map(str, replacements)

# join the resulting map operation to one string
''.join(string_replacements)

# should result in '12234'
```

Just need to make sure values are strings. in this case I mapped `str` over them as well to ensure that.

Eventually join the map result with `''.join` to get the wanted string.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your `test_string` and test each character against your dictionary like so:

```
printable = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4} 
#Sample string
test_string = 'abbcd'

finalList = []                             #Create List
for char in test_string:                   #For each character in the test string
    if char in printable:                  #Test to see if the key exists
        finalList.append(printable[char])  #Append the value to list

print(finalList)                           #Print the List
```